# Can this TestDBSet class from EF 6 be adapted to work with EF Core?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, mocking, entity-framework-core

I am trying to write my own test doubles for mock testing Entity Framework core by following this tutorial for EF 6:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/writing-test-doubles

The tutorial comes stuck on the TestDbSet class, which should provide an in-memory implementation of DbSet. However, most of the members are not compatible with EF Core:

```
public class TestDbSet<TEntity> : DbSet<TEntity>, IQueryable, IEnumerable<TEntity>, IDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    ObservableCollection<TEntity> _data;
    IQueryable _query;

    public TestDbSet()
    {
        _data = new ObservableCollection<TEntity>();
        _query = _data.AsQueryable();
    }

    public override TEntity Add(TEntity item)
    {
        _data.Add(item);
        return item;
    }

    public override TEntity Remove(TEntity item)
    {
        _data.Remove(item);
        return item;
    }

    public override TEntity Attach(TEntity item)
    {
        _data.Add(item);
        return item;
    }

    public override TEntity Create()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<TEntity>();
    }

    public override TDerivedEntity Create<TDerivedEntity>()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<TDerivedEntity>();
    }

    public override ObservableCollection<TEntity> Local
    {
        get { return _data; }
    }

    Type IQueryable.ElementType
    {
        get { return _query.ElementType; }
    }

    Expression IQueryable.Expression
    {
        get { return _query.Expression; }
    }

    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider
    {
        get { return new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<TEntity>(_query.Provider); }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _data.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator<TEntity> IEnumerable<TEntity>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _data.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IDbAsyncEnumerator<TEntity> IDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>.GetAsyncEnumerator()
    {
        return new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<TEntity>(_data.GetEnumerator());
    }
}
```

The error that occurs for the Add, Attach, Remove and Create methods is the same for all four:

> 'TestDbSet<TEntity>.Add(TEntity)': return type must be
>   'EntityEntry<TEntity>' to match overridden member
>   'DbSet<TEntity>.Add(TEntity)

Would anyone be able to explain if I can convert <TEntity> to EntityEntry<TEntity> or if there is a better way to work around the problem? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

For `EntityEntry<TEntity>`, it indicates the tracked TEntity and check the source code, it used `StateManager` to hanlde converting `TEntity` to `EntityEntry<TEntity>`.

You could not create `StateManager` in your `TestDbSet<TEntity>`.

Try to check whether code below work for you.

```
public class TestDbSet<TEntity> : DbSet<TEntity>, IQueryable, IEnumerable<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    ObservableCollection<TEntity> _data;
    IQueryable _query;

    public TestDbSet()
    {
        _data = new ObservableCollection<TEntity>();
        _query = _data.AsQueryable();
    }

    public override EntityEntry<TEntity> Add(TEntity item)
    {
        _data.Add(item);
        var entity = base.Attach(item);
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have been giving this a try, however the test breaks on the new line
 "var entity = base.Attach(item);"

with the error

"System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented."

Is there anything else I might have missed?

Comment: @EliRushbrook Do you need to work with return entity? If not, try `return item as EntityEntry<T>;` or `return null;`.

Answer (score 0):

@Edward your solution worked brilliantly, by returning null the tutorial is now compatible with EF core at least for my tests, thanks for the hint.

some modifications in TestContext:
- using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal;
- using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;
- change IDbAsyncEnumaerable and IDbAsyncEnumerator to IAsyncEnumerable and IAsyncEnumerator
- add, remove and attach methods: change return type from TEntity to EntityEntry and change last statement in each method to return null;
- some other methods will show compile error, just delete them.